# useState re-rendering component prevents animation from happening

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I've created a custom radio button that is supposed to have an animation when selected. I manage which one is selected in a state in its parent component. Seeing the behavior on the DOM tree in DevTools makes me think the problem is that on state change the whole parent component is being re-rendered and its children are deleted and added to tree instead of just changing the class, thus the animation of the css class doesn't run. Code example is simplified:

Child component

```
function RadioButton({
  children,
  value,
  onChange,
  selected
}: IRadioButtonProps): JSX.Element {

  const rootClasses = classNames('RadioButton-root', {
    'RadioButton-root-selected': selected
  });

  return (
    <RadioButtonContainer className={rootClasses} onClick={onClick}>
      <div className='RadioButton-icon'>
        <Done fontSize='inherit' className='RadioButton-icon-check' />
      </div>
      <div className='RadioButton-label'>{children}</div>
    </RadioButtonContainer>
  );
```

Parent

```
function HappyMeterForm(): JSX.Element {
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState<HappyMeterQuestion>();
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<HappyMeterOption[]>();
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<Guid>();


  useEffect(() => {
    HappyMeterManager.getHappyMeter()
      .then((happyMeter: HappyMeter) => {
        setQuestion(happyMeter.question);
        setOptions(happyMeter.options);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
      <>
        {question && options && (
          <>
            <div className='header'>
              <div className='title'>HappyMeter</div>
              <div className='subtitle'>{question.description}</div>
            </div>
            <div className='options'>
              {options.map((option) => (
                <Form.RadioButton
                  value={option.id}
                  onChange={setSelectedOption}
                  selected={selectedOption === option.id}
                >
                  {option.description}
                </Form.RadioButton>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div className='footer'>
              <Button
                onClick={onSend}
              >
                Send &gt;
              </Button>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </>
    );
```

The style that do the animation:

```
  .RadioButton-icon-check {
    max-width: 0px;
    transition: max-width 0.2s linear;
  }

  &.RadioButton-root-selected {
    .RadioButton-icon-check {
      max-width: 20px;
      transition: max-width 0.2s linear;
    }
```

The style seems ok, if I manually add and remove the class in DevTools it happens properly. If I change the content inside the header title to any other thing and select an option, it goes back to Happymeter, so I really think the whole component is being rendered again. I've tried to add a [key property](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to each option, but it didn't help. I've also tried to use a common variable (let selectedOption) with a new function to set its value, but then no changes happen at all although the new value can be seen on console.

How can I keep track of which option is selected rendering the options accordingly but not creating the whole component again when the state changes?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this?